# Author Identity unknown

Tags: git

I tried to commit my file to my repository, but git reported author unknown error message. It also said unable to auto-detect email address. what could be wrong? this is the error reported.
Author identity unknown

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address
```

Comment: Have you run these commands from output?

Comment: Is your question why Git cannot detect your email address?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Please+tell+me+who+you+are

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in your error message. Set your email and GitHub username using this commands.

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Replace **you@example.com** with your email address and **Your Name** with your username